# Center image in action bar Android

Tags: android, xml, styling

I'm having a custom action bar in android with an image which must be centered in the action bar. The "Brancom" image must be in the middle, but I can't get it working because of the hamburger icon which is besides it. How do I fix this? Here's what it looks like: http://gyazo.com/30eac941ea964c143012d470a2d76d3b

as you can see it's not in the center. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_brancom_actionbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    and then the rest of the code...
```

**edit**

this is what's happening: http://gyazo.com/c014f55d10aa0932a9ccbaea97bae674

**edit #2**

I figured it out by adding this, apparently the icon is 60dp so I subtracted that from the center after making it a relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_brancom_actionbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the gravity to ImageView like this and better use RelativeLayout instead of linearLayout:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Comment: a `RelativeLayout` just to center one view is like using a bazooka to kill a fly. A simple `FrameLayout` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You might transform your title image as a 9-patch or an XML drawable, so it can adapt to the size of the action bar, and use it as the action bar *background.*

Note that with this solution, if you have a lot of action items visible, they might go over the title image.

**Example of XML drawable**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/actionbar_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/title_image"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```